# Validation of Textbox Only Allowing Numbers and No Special Characters or Alpha

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I reedited my question from earlier but didn't see my new question get posted, so I'm reposting.  I apologize.

I'm very new to programming and in desperate need of help.  I'm using Asp.net with C# (Visual Studio 2017). I need to create a textbox that will ONLY allow 4 digits numbers, space key, and backspace.  No special characters or alpha are allowed.  The range has to be between 1899 to current year.  AND it needs to validate that the years entered in the textbox are within 1899-2021. AND i need a popup message saying "Invalid Year" when an incorrect year is entered in the textbox. I have tried numerous methods but nothing is working. Does anyone have codes I can use and please be clear as to where I need to insert them. The following is one set of sample code I've tried. However, for this one, I need the code to allow for space key and to only allow for 4 digits.  I also need to know where I should insert these codes.  The problem with this code is it has an up down button which I don't need. Hope this makes sense. Thank you!

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  function isValidYear() {

        var year = document.getElementById('tbxYear').value;

      
        if (year > 2021 || year < 1899) {

            alert("Range 1899 - 2021");

            return false;

        }

        return true;

     }

</script>
                          

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxYear" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static" type="number" min="1899" 
max="2021" step="1" onchange="isValidYear()" onpaste = "return false;" 
BorderColor="Black" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="auto-style8" 
Font-Names="Arial" Height="25px" MaxLength="4" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" 
ValidationGroup="check" Width="147px"> 
</asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
<span class="auto-style16">
<span class="auto-style15">
<b><span style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial; color: #FF0000">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you using ASP.NET Framework, or ASP.NET Core? A regular expression will do the trick but you're going to need to limit the characters. A simple helper method should work. I think I have one that may help with your issue.

Comment: You can use [RegularExpressionValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator?view=netframework-4.8) it's a good option. `\d{4}` could be the one solution.